# SWIG How to correctly wrap std::vector<double *>

Tags: c++, swig

Some c++ code we want to use with Java uses a vector of double pointers like so:

```
typedef std::vector<double *> VEC_pD;
```

I assumed wrapping it like so would suffice:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
%include "stl.i"

%pointer_class(double, doublep);
%template (VEC_pD) std::vector<double*>;
typedef std::vector<double *> VEC_pD;
```

While `double *` is correctly wrapped to doublep.java the wrapping of the vector does not use douplep but rather the autogenerated type `SWIGTYPE_p_double`.

I am using SWIG 4.0.2. Any hints how to tell the vector template how to use doublep are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `%template (VEC_pD) std::vector<doublep>;`.  I recently wrapped a `vector<vector<T>>` and used the wrapped name for `vector<T>` in the outer definition.  My wrapped name for `vector<T>` was also the C++ `typedef` for the same; I don't know if that mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Thx John, indeed switching to doublep generated the correct java class.

```
%template (VEC_pD) std::vector<doublep>;
```

Comment: I spoke to soon. With the above the wrapping of typedef std::vector<double *> VEC_pD; itself uses douplep. However, all uses in the code of VEC_pD now go to SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_double_p_t since the original vector of douple pointers is no longer wrapped.